# What's the involution elements in the permutation group of the natural number?

Tags: group-theory, combinations

Denote $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ as the permutation gourp of natural numbers, i.e. all of the bijections $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$. I wonder how the involution elments in  $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ look like?

Actually this quetion rises when I want to figure out what's the explict formula of number seris $a_{a_n}=n$,and this leads to the kind of functions in $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ of the form $f(f(x))=x$.

Note that if $f(m)=n$, then $f(n)=m$, which states $f$ is just compsitions of a series disjoint 2-permutations, i.e. $f=(i_1i_2)(i_3i_4)\ldots (i_mi_{m+1})\ldots$,where all of the $i_k$ is distinct and this series could be infinite.Is that right? Are there any relation to the elments of order 2 in the finite permutation group $S_n$ ?

**EDIT**:Thanks for the existing answer, and it seems that I get some defination mixed up. It seems that I'm not looking for idempotent elements but the involution ones, i.e. the order 2 elements in $S_{\mathbb{N}}$. So sorry about that. I have corrected it above.

Comment: An idempotents is an element such that $a^2=a.$ The rest of your question, after, seems to be seeking elements such that $a^2=\operatorname{Id}.$ Those are involutions, or elements of order $2.$

Answer (score 1):

Besides the identity, there is no idempotent permutation.

**Proof:** If $f$ is idempotent, then it verifies $f^2=f$.

Appy the inverse $f^{-1}$ of $f$ (which is known to exist since $f$ is a bijection) to that equation, and you get $$f=\text{Id}$$

Comment: Worth noting that there are no idempotents in *any* group. I’m pretty sure OP meant involutions, given the rest of the question.

Comment: Agreed. It's not really about permutations. Based on the second part of the question, OP might indeed have been after involutions.

Comment: Sorry about the mixed-up definition. What I really meant is just involutions.

Answer (score 0):

The involutions in any permutation group on a set $X$ are obtained by choosing some set of disjoint pairs (subsets of exactly two elements) in $X$, and forming the permutation that interchanges the elements in each such pair, while leaving all remaining elements of$~X$ fixed. This works in particular for $X=\Bbb N$. Choosing the empty set gives you the identity permutation, which is traditionally counted among the involutions (although it is not a permutation of order$~2$).

Comment: So this works for stuff like $\mathbb{R}$,right? What about the case of the sets with given topology, and  what if we consider a kind of "continous" involutions in this context, i.e. all of the involution homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$  to itself with the usual Euclidean topology?